# Excel idMso value for "Filter by Selected Cell's Value"

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot find the idMso value for the command "Filter by Selected Cell's Value" that appears on the contextual menu when right-clicking on a cell.

[image]

My goal is to intercept this command and do some additional VBA work around the act of filtering, which is what I am currently able to do for the Ribbon's "Filter" command with the following RibbonUI XML.

> ```
> <commands>
>     <command idMso="Filter" onAction="UserList_Main.RepurposeCommand" />
> </commands>
> ```

Anyone know what this idMso should be?

(While we're at it, the other commands from that contextual menu could be useful as well, though By Value is the important one.)

Comment: Have you tried `AutoFilter`?

Comment: Yep, and that's not it.

Comment: Okay, how about `AutoFilterClassic`? I'm guessing it has to be on this list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd909393(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Sadly, it's not on that list. I've tried everything there that looks even remotely filter-related, with no luck.